# SFTP move files within remote dir

Tags: linux, rename, sftp, move

I need to move files between remote directories.  It will always be multiple files and there is no naming convention to work with.  Is there any way to use the rename command with a wildcard?

For example:

```
rename /dir1/dir2/* /dir1/dir2/history/
```

This does not work, it returns the following error:

```
Couldn't rename file "/dir1/dir2/*" to "/dir1/dir2/history": No such file or directory
```

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What library / language / development tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `rename`, is this a SFTP command?

Anyway, you don't have to use SFTP. You can use SSH like this:

```
ssh user@fqdn "mv /dir1/dir2/* /dir1/dir2/history/"
```

Comment: You can not SSH to all servers to which you can SFTP